# Scroll bar takes time to appear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, scrollbar, iscroll4

I found JS ready to use a scroll bar in Mobile this site: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

My list is filled with autocomplete in input ..

Takes a few minutes to scroll bar appears.(Sometimes displays after several minutes and sometimes not displayed at all)

until it appears when I try to drag down, the list jumps up

anyone have any idea why this is happening?

My JS:

```
 myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');// **in Document.ready**
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <ul class="Result" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" dir="rtl">
            </ul>
        </div>
```

My css:

```
#wrapper
{
    z-index: 5000;
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 37%;
}
```

Comment: what is the page load time ?

Comment: Not defined .. What is the default?

Comment: I meant how much time is the page taking to load ? As all the methods called under `document.ready` method will be called only once the document is completely ready. In other words when the page has finished loading. Here it seems like the page is taking time to load and scroll bar method is called when the document gets to the ready state.

Comment: I have several functions in Document.ready, the last one is running scroll .. Can this be the problem?

Comment: in case processing other methods takes time, Yes it may be. Also, Do note that if any of the methods defined above the scroll method breaks the scroll method will not be initiated at all.

Comment: I am working with chrome and I noticed now that only by pressing F12, the scroll is displayed.

Comment: you mean the scroll bar is displayed only when you open the developer utility in chrome ? Is there enough content on the page for the scroll bar to be initiated ?

Comment: Yes scroll bar is on a list long enough .. Because when I close the F12 is staying ... Not disappear back.

Comment: I also see that I can scroll to bottom, but this always jumps back top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem this way:

Need to refresh the scroll each time the size of the list changes

Because it takes time for AutoComplete to fill, I refresh the scroll only after some time.

function on key press in the input:

```
function RefreshScroll() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        MyScroll.scrollToElement('li:nth-child(1)', 100)
        setTimeout(function () {
            MyScroll.refresh();
        }, 0);
    }, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe:

```
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {fadeScrollbar: false});
```

Comment: Now is not scrolling at all

Comment: Also did not help, I realized that only if I press F12 in Chrome, the scroll bar appears, when click on an element from the list I need the list div disappears,the list is cleared and remains only a scroll bar, which means that the list div has not disappeared, and when I pressed F12 is gone, it seems to me the problems of Chrome, but in Firefox scroll bar does not appear at all

Comment: On a smartphone takes time to scroll bar appears, but it appears finally .. Is there a way to shorten the time?